# How can I correct this Jasper so that the text field stretches its height to show all 500 characters of a string

Tags: jasper-reports

I've already set strecth type to "tallest object" but didn't work. The field is "objeto". The only field that is going to have a lot of characters is f{objeto}, it will have up to 500 characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="estimativa_processo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="entidade" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="estado" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <parameter name="setor" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="titulo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="inventario" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="numeroRpl" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="secretaria" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tipo_requisicao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="objeto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="justificativa" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="formato_contratacao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="local_entrega" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="requerente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="observacao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dt_abertura" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="responsavel" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="lbl_formato" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="estimativa_consumo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="media_processo" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="nome_fornecedor" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ddd_fone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="cnpj_cpf" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data_atual" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Requisicao">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{numeroRpl}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="372">
                <image hAlign="Center">
                    <reportElement key="image-1" x="147" y="2" width="256" height="56"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-140" x="1" y="69" width="553" height="28"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{entidade}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="-1" y="117" width="556" height="21"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{titulo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement key="textField-139" x="1" y="98" width="553" height="19"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{estado}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="6" y="288" width="127" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Estimativa de Consumo:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="157" width="554" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="186" width="103" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Secretaria: ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="6" y="162" width="42" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[RPL:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="7" y="252" width="539" height="32"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{objeto}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="51" y="157" width="1" height="27"/>
                </line>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="231" width="103" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Objeto: ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="184" width="553" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="133" y="289" width="127" height="17"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{estimativa_consumo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="56" y="162" width="133" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{numeroRpl}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="7" y="208" width="539" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{secretaria}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="6" y="310" width="127" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Média do Processo:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="333" width="126" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Fornecedores Cotados:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="352" width="103" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Nome]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="232" y="352" width="103" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[CNPJ/CPF]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="384" y="352" width="103" height="18"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Telefone]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement x="133" y="310" width="127" height="17"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{media_processo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="554" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="1" height="369"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="555" y="2" width="1" height="370"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="371" width="555" height="1"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="130">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="147" y="85" width="288" height="18"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{responsavel}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="169" y="83" width="248" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="169" y="20" width="248" height="19"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{data_atual}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="555" y="0" width="1" height="130"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="130"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="129" width="554" height="1"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="Fornecedor">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome_fornecedor}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="22">
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="555" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
                </line>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="385" y="2" width="161" height="17"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["(" + $F{ddd_fone} + ") " + $F{fone}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="233" y="2" width="128" height="17"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{cnpj_cpf}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="2" width="205" height="17"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{nome_fornecedor}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add float position for everything you can and set the "lines" to stretch with band.